# Html table scraping using Rvest with dropdown boxes

Tags: html, r, web-scraping, html-table, rvest

I would like to scrape a html table using `rvest` which has three dropdown boxes. When i select the option from the three, it will give a html table with no submit button. The website looks like this

These are three options (cascade line 1/cascade line 2 ), (date) and (shift A /shift B /shift C). This gives me error when i try to select cascade table 1 alone.

```
station_id <- url %>% html_nodes("#select.cascade_selection,table")  %>% html_attr("1") %>% 
                      html_table()
```

> Error in UseMethod("html_table") :    no applicable method for
>   'html_table' applied to an object of class "character"

How i do give all the three options and get the table using rvest ? Below added the inspect element of each options

```
     <select class="form-control  select2-hidden-accessible" style="width: 100%;" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true" id="cascade_selection" onchange="shiftSelection(0,2)">
           <option value="1" selected="selected">Cascade Line 1</option>
           <option value="2">Cascade Line 2</option>
          </select>


<div class="input-group date">
            <div class="input-group-addon">
             <i class="fa fa-calendar"/>
            </div>
            <input type="text" class="form-control pull-left" id="dateRangeSelected" style="background:white;" data-disable-touch-keyboard=""/>
           </div>
           <!--/.input group-->


    <select class="form-control  select2-hidden-accessible" style="width: 100%;" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true" id="shift_selection" onchange="shiftSelection(0,2)">
               <option value="A" selected="selected">Shift A</option>
               <option value="B">Shift B</option>
               <option value="C">Shift C</option>
              </select>
```

Comment: The site URL wld be handy. There is likely a pretty easy way to do this via `httr::GET`. It looks like this may be an internal site so you may not be able to provide a URL. I'd open Developer Tools, then go to that site, interact with that form and see what shows up in the XHR sub-tab of the Network tab. There is likely a JSON file.